# How can I determine the total storage size of data stored in both folders and subdirectories within Azure Data Lake?

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have stored data in Azure data lake in different folders and sub folders. I want to know the size of the data stored.

I am looking for some function/code which we can run in azure data bricks to run that recursively which will give us the size of data.

Comment: what error you are facing??

Comment: I made some mistakes in the code itself it seems. Now made the changes and running fine. Updated the code in the question itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code I tried initially was hitting some error because of some mistake.
**Below code works properly -**

```
    %python
    # Specify the root path to your ADLS Gen2 container
    root_path = “abfss://<container-name>@<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net/<Path>”

    # Function to calculate the size of a directory and its subdirectories recursively
    def calculate_directory_size(directory_path):
        total_size = 0
        for file_info in dbutils.fs.ls(directory_path):
           if file_info.isDir():
              total_size += calculate_directory_size(file_info.path)
           else:
              total_size += file_info.size
        return total_size

    # List all directories within the root path
    directories = [f.path for f in dbutils.fs.ls(root_path) if f.isDir()]

    # Calculate and print the size of each directory and its subdirectories
    for directory in directories:
        directory_name = directory.split("/")[-1]
        print("directory", directory)
        directory_size = calculate_directory_size(directory)
        print(f"Data volume in {directory_name}: {directory_size} bytes")

        # Convert bytes to gigabytes (GB) for readability
        directory_size_gb = directory_size / (1024 ** 3)
        print(f"Data volume in {directory_name}: {directory_size_gb:.5f} GB")
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach? In this case, highlighting what the original mistake was and what you changed would be really useful.

Comment: @JeremyCaney - Thank you for your comments. I will definitely keep that in mind in my posts.

Comment: @Shikha - Glad to know that your issue has resolved. You can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: @cheekatalapradeep - Just did. Thank you !

Comment: Awesome, it is working, Thanks :)